# How can I use the MAX function to retrieve the max date of field in a table in another database?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a database (DB1) and would like to use the DMAX function to extract the maximum date of a field called "RunDate" in a table (tbl1) located in another database (DB2).

This is for a project that I am working on that compares the dates in two different databases.  I am using SAS to ftp several text files from a mainframe into an access database (DB1).  I wish to compare the dates of the tables in DB1 to the corresponding tables in another database (DB2).  If the RunDates in DB1 are greater than those in DB2, I would like to append DB1 data to the corresponding tables in DB2 .

```
Date1= DMAX("[RunDate]","C:\path\to\.mdb file")
Date2= DMAX("[RunDate]","E:\path\to\.mdb file")
```

If Date1 > Date2 Then I would like to append tables.

Answer (score 0):

Create a *link* to each of the tables in the two databases. Then it will be:

```vb
Date1 = DMax("[RunDate]", "NameOfLinkedTable1")
Date2 = DMax("[RunDate]", "NameOfLinkedTable2")
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid links.  There will be about 60 tables and I would like to avoid the clutter.

Comment: You mentioned 2, not 60, so how could we know? But link them as you need them, and delete the links when done. Fast and easy and no "clutter".

Comment: Is it possible to use DMAX?